# Load more data when ScrollView is scrolled to bottom

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I've got a scrollView with dinamically loading content. Sometimes there can be a lot of content, so I would like to load more when user scrolls to bottom.

I searced for suitable metods and found two:

```
onScrollChanged()
```

and

```
getScrollY()
```

But I dont know how to use it for my purposes.
Please give me some advice.

Comment: Why not use a `ListView`? This is what it does

Comment: I need some views configuration that listview doesn't allow. (Show photos like in pinterest)

Comment: I don't use pinterest so I don't know their layout but I am working on something right now that allows you to take a picture and display it in the listview. Like SpongeBob says, Anything is possible with imagination, yes I have kids :)

Comment: @codeMagic +1 for imagination!

Answer (score 12):

Scroll view does not provide any method to check if you've reached bottom of the view  so the best technique is to extend your own custom view with scroll view . This is how i implemented in my app.

**Step 1:Create a custom class for scroll view**

```
public class ObservableScrollView extends ScrollView {

private ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener = null;

public ObservableScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setScrollViewListener(ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener) {
    this.scrollViewListener = scrollViewListener;
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {

    View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
    int diff = (view.getBottom() - (getHeight() + getScrollY()));
    if (diff == 0) { // if diff is zero, then the bottom has been reached
        if (scrollViewListener != null) {
            scrollViewListener.onScrollEnded(this, x, y, oldx, oldy);
        }
    }
    super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldx, oldy);
}
```

}

**Step 2:Create a scroll view Listener Interface**

```
public interface ScrollViewListener {

void onScrollEnded(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy);



 }
```

**Step 3:Add the view in your layout**

```
   <com.platinumapps.facedroid.ObservableScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </com.platinumapps.facedroid.ObservableScrollView>
```

**Step 4:Implement that interface in your class**

```
  public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements ScrollViewListener 

@Override
public void onScrollEnded(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx,   int oldy) {

           //Perform your action
}
```

**And you are done**

Comment: unable to get diff 0 getting diff directly less then 0

Answer (score 7):

I think the better way would be to use `ListView`.But if you only required `ScrollView`.

First you fix a threshold height of your `ScrollView` so whenever you crosses that limit load new data & append to `ScrollView` & reset your threshold height.

This is how you can try..

Create a customized `ScrollView` like this.

```
public class ObservableScrollView extends ScrollView
{

    private ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener = null;

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setScrollViewListener(ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener)
    {
        this.scrollViewListener = scrollViewListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy)
    {
        super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldx, oldy);
        if (scrollViewListener != null)
        {
            scrollViewListener.onScrollChanged(this, x, y, oldx, oldy);
        }
    }

}
```

& then create an interface

```
public interface ScrollViewListener 
{
    void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy);
}
```

& your XML layout should be like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.solve.stackoverflow.ObservableScrollView
        android:id="@+id/endless_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/endless_scrollview_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </com.solve.stackoverflow.ObservableScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

& finally use all these in your Activity

```
public class EndLessActivity extends Activity implements ScrollViewListener
{
    ObservableScrollView scrollView;
    LinearLayout layout;

    int threshold = 20; //Setting threshold 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.endless_scrollview);
        scrollView = (ObservableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.endless_scrollview);
        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.endless_scrollview_layout);
        scrollView.setScrollViewListener(this);
        appendData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (y > threshold)
             appendData();
    }

    void appendData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            threshold += 10;//Reseting threshold.
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            layout.addView(tv);
        }
    }
}
```

Try this & let me know, whether it solve your problem or not.

Thanks